# How can I install Google play services on Android 2.2?

Tags: google-play-store, google-play-services

I have an unbranded tablet running android 2.2.

I was trying to develop an application using gcm and wanted to test it on the tablet. But somehow SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE error was coming. I then came to know that for android devices having version less than 4.2.2 , google play services has to be installed in the device for GCM to work.

Firstly, i tried to search for Google Play Services on PlayStore app. No result was shown. So instead i tried searching for it on phone's browser.
So when i saw the link on browser, a popup appeared asking for whether to open with browser or Playstore. I chose playstore and the link opened.
Which was kinda surprising because no result was shown earlier when searching through Playstore.

Secondly, when i tried to install the app it gave an error saying that Incompatible with other applications(s) using the sameshared user ID.

So, this means i cant test GCM on my device.
Any advice ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: As far as I know the Google Play Services are installed automatically on the device, maybe because your tablet is unbranded it detects as some kind of incompatibility. Does your tablet have any model number? If yes, try searching for this model specifically

Comment: possible duplicate of [Install google play service: Incompatible with other applications(s) using the same shared user ID](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/50328/install-google-play-service-incompatible-with-other-applicationss-using-the-s)

Answer (score 2):

I've just found the Google Play Services on the Play Store, [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms). Try opening this link on a desktop webbrowser and login into your Google account, then your tablet must be registered to your account, right? If it has any restrictions, the restriction will be shown to you when you try to hit install.

Comment: I downloaded the app from [here](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-store/google-play-store-4-9-13-3-release/#notes), because I needed for Froyo (android 2.2).

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember what version was original in 2.2 Froyo.

Here is a nice article listing all Android Versions, Support levels, and Features! I stand corrected, according to the info in the article below, on Android 4.x.

On March 6, 2012, the Google Play store was announced, merging the Android Market, Google Music, and the Google eBookstore. This update rolled out to devices running Android 2.2 or later.

https://www.lifewire.com/android-versions-4173277

I believe it's time for more than a 2G phone.  Sorry.  A phone that old has so little RAM, few than the factory-installed apps could be installed anyway.  I still stand by my "old phone" comments.

good luck!