# CM11 Kindle Fire - "Incompatible with other applications(s) using the same shared user ID" with Google Calendar

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.4-kitkat, google-apps, amazon-kindle

I'm running Cyanogenmod 11 (KitKat 4.4.4) on my 1st Gen (Otter) Kindle Fire, with GApps installed.

I can install other apps just fine, I installed Slack with no issues. However, when I went to install Google Calendar, I got this error:

```
Incompatible with other applications(s) using the same shared user ID
```

I've been looking through forums and I haven't found anything that has fixed it. I've tried a fresh GApps installation, wiping the cache, reinstalling the ROM, nothing has worked. I tried to look into the files and could not find a `packages.xml` file, so I cannot take out the line of code I've seen mentioned that could be causing issues.

I'm seriously stumped by this and would love any input!

Comment: Related: [Google Calendar install error: Incompatible with other application(s) using the same shared user ID](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/58480/16575) / [“Incompatible with other applications(s) using the same shared user ID” when installing Google Play service?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/50328/16575)

Comment: I've tried all of the solutions listed here numerous times and they failed to help. One issue was only fixed after an updated ROM was released, and this ROM is one of the most current.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this, I had to install the APK file myself for Google Calendar after downloading it and allowing my device to accept 3rd party apps. Since then I've had no issues!