# Unable to install Google Play Services to save Clash of Clans village

Tags: google-play-services, clash-of-clans

I play Clash of Clans and I have a village which I do not want to lose.

I am attempting to save the village to Google Play Services but I am not able to install Play Services as it says that it is not compatible with other apps. How can I save my village without services, or how can I install Google Play Services?

My device is Maxx AX5 with Android 4.0.4 and kernel version 3.0.13.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Incompatible with other applications(s) using the same shared user ID" when installing Google Play service?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/50328/incompatible-with-other-applicationss-using-the-same-shared-user-id-when-ins)

Comment: Well, @bmdixon no this is not duplicate of the thread you have mentioned over here. Here the user is concerned about saving his progress of the game i.e. IGG ID and over the thread you have mentioned the user is seeking help over Google Plays and Google Plus.

Comment: "it is not compatible with other apps" Anything more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Part 1 of your question can be answered in the bottom half of the following link. Requires Google+

https://gamesupport.supercell.net/hc/en-us/articles/421682-Can-I-transfer-my-village-to-a-new-device-

Part 2 of your question can be accomplished by flash the proper GApps package to your device. Goto XDA forum and do a search for your device and GApps package for version of Android that you are using