# How to transfer a Clash of Clans Village into an old Android device without Google Play services?

Tags: google-play-services, clash-of-clans

I can't install Google Play services on my old device. I tried a lot, but I can't.

Is there any way to transfer the game data onto an old device?

I have tried to transfer the app+data using Titanium Backup, but the old device just generates a new village.

Is there any other way? or any app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to install Google Play Services to save Clash of Clans village](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/79361/unable-to-install-google-play-services-to-save-clash-of-clans-village)

Comment: doesn't worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Read this, the bottom half is for android users, https://gamesupport.supercell.net/hc/en-us/articles/421682-Can-I-transfer-my-village-to-a-new-device-
This doesn't require Play Services, but does require G+. You should be able do this w/o Google Play Services

Good luck!

Comment: @user3551620 Don't be hard on yourself, it takes a long time to get this stuff sorted out. I know its aggravating, but keep your chin up!! Before you know it you'll be a whiz!!

Comment: I know and i am sorry about that, you was just trying to help.