# Unlock android phone with forgotten password and attached gmail account details too

Tags: locked-out, google-account

Unfortunately My android phone Sony Xperia Go with got locked. I gave this to a friend for use and he gave this to his friend. Now the problem is no one have any idea which gmail account is linked to this. Neither any one is taking the responsibility... well that's other problem.

I am writing here for help. If anyone can help in this.

The phone is not allowing to enter pattern now. It is asking for gmail account details or security question answer and don't have any of these.

I hope anyone could help me this.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't worry for the data of your phone the everything will be easier.First of all turn off the device.Then open it again, wait 3 seconds and then press the power button and the volume up or down(the reboot may differ from phone to phone) Then, at the reboot you will be able to use it only with the up and down volume buttons.Reset the phone and everything will be deleted (even the password) For more information check here : http://www.greenbot.com/article/2458403/how-to-perform-a-factory-reset-on-your-android-phone-or-tablet.html

Comment: I tried this Reboot but it didn't worked.

Comment: That link won't help because he can't get into the phone. Also, links to provide reference are fine in answers, but the answer should contain all the information on what to do, and the link is just the reference. this is so if the link is no longer valid, the answer would still be.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to solve this, because you don't know what account it is tied to is to perform a [factory reset](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6422/what-is-hard-reset-and-what-is-factory-reset).

The steps here are for Xperia P, which I think is the Xperia Go. If it's not, these steps may still work for that phone and other Xperia devices.

To boot into recovery :

1. Power off the phone
2. Wait for about 10 - 30 seconds after the device is off.
3. Power the phone back on and the time when you see your phone's LED notification changes to a color, start pressing either the Volume UP or Volume Down button a couple of times to make your phone boot into recovery mode. *If it doesn't go into recovery here, turn off and try again.*
4. Once in recovery, use the volume up and volume down buttons to navigate to the Factory Reset option. Use the power button to select the item.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have home button at your phone. If you have try to do the same but with power button and hone button.

Comment: there is no home button