# How to enter in recovery mode htc desire 326g?

Tags: recovery-mode

When I press and hold vol. up & power button it goes to "safe mode", when vol.-& power button shows "fastboot mode". But I want to get a hard reset. Please help me . My Model is HTC Desire 326g.

Comment: You don't need to enter recovery mode for a hard reset. Just remove the battery, and you're done :) What you probably want is a factory-reset, see: [What is hard reset and what is factory reset?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/6422/16575)

Answer (score 0):

#### To factory-reset your HTC desire 326g:

1. At the very beginning use the <kbd>Power</kbd> key in order to switch off the device.
2. Afterwards press and hold <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> + <kbd>Power</kbd> button at the same time for a couple of seconds.
3. When u see three Android images, release the buttons held.
4. Then press <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> to select option "Factory reset", and press <kbd>Power</kbd> button to confirm.
5. Good job! The factory reset has just been performed.

<sup>(Source: [HardReset.Info](http://www.hardreset.info/devices/htc/htc-desire-326g/))</sup>

Comment: Note: Next to some nice formattings, I've replaced "hard reset" by "factory reset". A "hard reset" is simply a "power cut" (e.g. taking off the battery), see our [hard-reset tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/hard-reset/info) (and [What is hard reset and what is factory reset?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/6422/16575)). The two are quite often confused. Oh, and credit to whom [credit belongs](http://www.hardreset.info/devices/htc/htc-desire-326g/), right? ;)

Answer (score -1):

Hi  you are hard reset your HTC desire 326g so first root your HTC 
For kigroot
Second:,you are a pc 
                          Then you made cwm img for HTC 
After then your made image
Third: go to play store and download Rom manager and install cwm img

So you complete all stap
Swatch off your phone and press volume down+power button 
Then you got recovery mod
(For made cwm img for any phone with pc  go YouTube )